# Ionic4 How to combine split pane & tabs and check routes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routerlink

i need help please
Can you help me please to combine ion-tabs inside split pane, and verify is my routes are corrects please.
i do some try and test but i don’t understand how to configure correctly routes and router-outlet

you can try on stackblitz :

https://stackblitz.com/github/Celtiore/ionic4-angular-tests-RouterLink

or github :

https://github.com/Celtiore/ionic4-angular-tests-RouterLink

thanks you